# Setup vscode to compile C files

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

Im trying to setup vscode to compile and run C files, but I am having problems with setting up the tasks.json file.

I guess what I'm really asking is how to include code from outside the main file. Im trying to include a file "stack.h" from a folder "include" but it's not working.

I get this error in vscode:

> ld: can't link with a main executable file 'gcc' for architecture
>   x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
>   see invocation) The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

My tasks.json file looks like this

```
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "gcc build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "args": [
                "gcc",
                "-o",
                "stack_test",
                "-I${fileDirname}/../include/",
                "${file}",
                "${fileDirname}/../src/stack/stack.c",
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

I can compile this file normally through the terminal with the following

```
gcc -o stack_test -I../include/ stack_test.c ../src/stack/stack.c
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Suggest you add `-Wall` to arguments! Or even `-Werror` too!

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that the compiler is not in the platform path. Visual Studio Code is therefore not able to find it.

See: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp

Comment: I wish it was that easy, unfortunately I have set up the platform path. I only get this problem when I try to include other files and use the "-I" gcc flag.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with VS Code and I resolved it by doing this. Maybe it can help someone. (I used this video solution [here](https://youtu.be/8IWFeUkZ4bo))

The C compiler needs to have all c files addressed when it starts to compile like when you are doing it in the terminal.

1. Please open `.vscode/task.json` or `.vscode/launch.json` on the left side, the project explorer.
2. in part of `"args":[],` you can see `"${file}",` please change it to `"${workspacefolder}/*.cpp"`

   Note: Please,

   - A: For Unix/Linux use `/` and for windows use `\`,
   - B: If you have c files add `..../*.c`.
   - C: If you have files with different extensions or different directories, please add multiple lines as in this sample:

   ```
   "args": [
   "${workspacefolder}/*.cpp",
   "${workspacefolder}/*.c",
   "${workspacefolder}/subDir/*.cpp",
   "${workspacefolder}/subDir/*.c"
   ],
   ```
3. Save changes
4. Retry to compile or debug.